No Scan With HP LaserJet Pro MFP M130nw
Scanning with HP LaserJet Pro MFP M130nw stopped without any fresh install (updates installed though). Printing and Copying work fine. While launching a scan through Document Scanner, I get 'Scan Failed' and 'Unable To Connect To Scanner' messages. I tried this link, but the problem persists!
What is needed to be done?
Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS; OS type 64-bit; GNOME Version 46; Kernel Version Linux 6.8.0-49-generic
Thanks for the participating.
